# Texture Paint suddenly changes color

Tags: texture-painting

I was painting a figure. I hit 'S' to get the color picker to save the colors I was using for clothes, then I saved the color I used for skin. I painted some of the clothing, then went back to the skin. Suddenly the brush is using a different color. I pick the skin color again, and it goes back to the other color (yellow in the screenshot color).

I removed the earlier color and picked it again. It made no difference. I got rid of it and color picked from a different part of the figure. No difference.[image]

Comment: What version of Blender are you using for this? Do you mean that you press S to sample and then save as a swatch there? Do you then press S on top of the swatch, or are you just pressing the swatch to switch to it?

Comment: I'm using version 2.8. I press S to sample and save it as a swatch. Then I click on it later after I've saved it.